# Java, Exception, the best way, exam preparations

Tags: java

I'm preparing for an exam in basic programming. I'm working on exceptions now but can't seem to figure out how to best use it. I give you the first code and then the second where I try to make a checked exceptions. Any input on this would make me grateful!

**without the exceptions:**

```
public boolean uttak(int species, int kroner, int skilling) {
     if (species<=this.species && kroner<=this.kroner && skilling <=this.skilling)
     {
         this.species -=species;
         this.kroner -=kroner;
         this.skilling -=skilling;
         return true;
     }
     else return false;
```

**with my messy exceptions :**

```
public void uttak(int species, int kroner, int skilling){
    try{
       if (species<=this.species && kroner<=this.kroner && skilling <=this.skilling)
        {
            this.species -=species;
            this.kroner -=kroner;
            this.skilling -=skilling;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println ("Withdrawals can not be done when there is" +
                             " insufficient money in the machine.");
    }
```

Comment: Please reformat your code, it's unreadable

Comment: And post code in English, otherwise we can't understand anything about it.

Comment: Exceptions should only be used for stuff that breaks normal logic. Is that the case here?

Comment: Do you really suspect the code to throw an exception?

Comment: In your code I don't see any exception that will be thrown so your try-catch block is useless.

Comment: @aleb2000 There is always the possibility of an exception.  `Integer species = null; Integer kroner = null; Integer skilling = null; uttak(species, kroner, skilling);`.  But I agree that the try-catch block is useless.

Comment: I have to make exeption, Im working on an old exam where they ask us to transform the code we have written to rather throw an exeption.

Comment: @enory your code won't explode in the try block. Only if the fields are null Integers will it explode in the try block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are looking for something like this:

```
// custom checked exception type
public class WithdrawalException extends Exception {
     public WithdrawalException(String msg) {
         super(msg);
     }
}
```

```
public boolean uttak(int species, int kroner, int skilling) throws WithdrawalException { // checked exceptions need to be declared in the throws clause 
     if (species<=this.species && kroner<=this.kroner && skilling <=this.skilling)
     {
         this.species -=species;
         this.kroner -=kroner;
         this.skilling -=skilling;
         return true;
     }
     else
         // throw an exception
         throw new WithdrawalException("Withdrawals can not be done when there is insufficient money in the machine.");
}
```

And use it in the calling code like this

```
try {
    uttak(i1, i2, i3);
} catch (WithdrawalException ex) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong. Message: "+ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them is correct to me (if that's a topic about exceptions).

It is a good way to throw *an unchecked exception* when one of the method parameters doesn't satisfy logic of its method:

```
if (species > this.species || kroner > this.kroner || skilling > this.skilling) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("message");
}
```

If you are encountered with a logical issue during the method execution, you should normally throw *a checked exception* (your own subclass of the `Exception`, or any other specific checked exception):

```
if (species > this.species || kroner > this.kroner || skilling > this.skilling) {
    throw new MyCustomCheckedException("message");
}
```

There is no reason to handle an exception on this level (assuming that it is thrown somewhere in the `try` block, though it isn't in your case).

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure how to use "throw" "try" and "catch". Im working with some old exams :)

Comment: @Muriel, what difficulties are you struggling with?

Comment: This is very bad idea. There's nothing wrong with the arguments.  The problem is the account has insufficient funds. You should throw a domain exception.

Comment: I used Andrews code now, It looks like this ( translated message "not enough funds" (sort of) )

Comment: public void uttak(int species, int kroner, int skilling)
     {
     if (species>this.species || kroner>this.kroner ||skilling>this.skilling)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uttak overstiger automatens kapasitet");
     else
     { this.species -=species;
       this.kroner -=kroner;
       this.skilling -=skilling;
       

     }
    }

Comment: I haven¨t worked woth exeptions at all Andrew. And I know it will come on my exam. So I am kind of struggling with all of it! But this was a good solution. I still dont feel safe as to when to use the "try" and catch" though ....